# Aperture Project IDs when multiple projects are selected

Tags: applescript

I am trying to get the Project IDs of multiple selected projects in the library. When only one project is selected, an image version is also selected in the browser so I can access the id with:

```
tell application "Aperture"
    tell item 1 of (selection as list) to set projId to parent's id
end tell
```

However, when multiple projects are selected, no image version is selected in the browser so the above will not work. I know I can resort to UI to select a picture and then loop through to extract the id's but I would like to avoid doing so.

```
activate application "Aperture"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Aperture"
        keystroke (ASCII character 29) -- Right
    end tell
end tell
```

What is the best way of getting project id's for the selected project or projects in Aperture?